# Panasonic Lumix G 42.5mm F/1.2 vs Panasonic Lumix G 42.5mm f/1.7 ASPH Power O.I.S

Tags: lens, aperture, image-quality, bokeh, panasonic-lumix

How much of a difference these two lenses will make in photo quality and what will be the difference? I am a newbie in photo and I am looking to invest in a nice lens for 4/3 that has max features in it - bokeh, zoom, night/evening pics etc.

Could someone explain to me the difference between the two? they cons and pros?

Context: I travel and hike a lot, I like to take portraits, landscapes, pictures of flowers and nature.

I own Olympus OMD10 mark ii (btw would Panasonic lens work on Olympus camera?)

[image]

Comment: Comparing features only makes sense in context. What are you looking for a new lens *for*? What led you to these in particular?

Comment: If you’re looking for zoom, I think you’ve chosen the wrong lens...these don’t zoom.

Comment: @mattdm updated context :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea which is "better", but I'd *guess* the *Leica Nocticron* 42.5/1.2 because it has "Leica" in the name. Also the list price is 3.4x the other.

They will both give a field of view equivalent to an 85mm on full frame. F1.2 will look like F2.4 on full frame. F1.7 will look like F3.5 on full frame. As far as light-gathering ability, they are a fraction of a stop away from each other.

Sample images on Flickr for both lenses look nice. If this is the focal length you want/need, either lens would likely work. Go to a store that will let you try them out.

- Flickr: [Panasonic 42.5 f/1.2](https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=panasonic%2042.5mm%20f%2F1.2)
- Flickr: [Panasonic 42.5 f/1.7](https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=panasonic%2042.5mm%20f%2F1.7)

As far as zoom is concerned, as [Hueco points out](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/106534/panasonic-lumix-g-42-5mm-f-1-2-vs-panasonic-lumix-g-42-5mm-f-1-7-asph-power-o-i/106556#comment204284_106534), *both* lenses receive a *failing* grade.